# google compute engine webserver: limit access to a few google-accounts

Tags: google-compute-engine

I want to protect the access to a webserver listening on port 80 running on a google compute engine vm-instance. the access to the webserver should only be allowed to special google-accounts. With App engine this was possible to implement with IAM. I cannot found anything about this for compute engine. Is there a way to limit the access to the webserver only for a few google-accounts?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can see is by adding Firewall rules excluding all traffic on port 80 except for some IP addresses. Here is the [firewall documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) which will explain how to create firewall rules including the filters and priorities.   I also found this [post on StackExchange](https://serverfault.com/questions/901364/restrict-access-to-single-ip-only) that worth to be mentioned.

Another solution is using [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview). The implementation is a [bit more complex](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-compute-howto) than simple firewall rules but this access control model will allow specific users to reach your resources.